# Value of joint CDF at $x=-\infty, y=+\infty$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

I want to find the Value of joint CDF at $x=-\infty, y=+\infty, F_{XY}(-\infty,+\infty)$

> My attempt

$F_{XY}(-\infty,+\infty) = \int_{x=-\infty}^{-\infty}\int_{y=-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{XY}(x,y) dydx \\ = \int_{x=-\infty}^{-\infty} f_X(x) dx \\ = 0$

But in classnotes, it is answer is given as 1. I am not able to find where i went wrong. Kindly correct me.

Comment: You seem to have some mixture of $x=\infty$ and $x=-\infty$

Comment: sir pls see above. I typed it wrongly

Comment: $0$ is correct for $F_{XY}(-\infty,+\infty)$ (assuming $x$ only takes real values) while $1$ is correct for $F_{XY}(+\infty,+\infty)$

Comment: thank you sir. ........

Answer (score 1):

$F(x,y)=P(X\le x, Y\le y)$. Hence, $F(\infty,\infty)=P(X< \infty,Y<\infty)=1$

On the other hand,

$F(-\infty,\infty)=P(X< -\infty,Y<\infty)=0$